# ¿Cómo cuento cuántos dígitos tiene un número entero?

Tags: python

He probado con esto:

```
def contar_digitos(numero):
    digitos = 0
    for n in numero :
    digitos += 1
return digitos

num = input("Introduzca su número: ")
resultado = contar_digitos(numero)

print("Cantidad de digitos {}".format(resultado))
```

Comment: len(str(numero))??

Comment: En realidad `len(num)` en este ejemplo sería suficiente, ya que lo que retorna `input()` , que es guardado en `num`, ya es una cadena

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Aportas un código, ¿te funciona?

Comment: Y qué pasó cuando probaste? Con qué entradas probaste? Qué debería salir? Qué salió en su lugar? QUé errores encontraste? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta es:

```
print(len(input("numero").strip()))
```

**Explicación**

`input("numero")` retorna un string que, además de los dígitos ingresados, contiene posibles espacios en blancos antes y/o después del número y también un `\n` al final (o `\r\n`, dependiendo de la plataforma).

Con `.strip()` remuevo todos los *white spaces* mencionados, dejando la cadena reducida a puros dígitos.

`len()` devuelve el largo de la cadena resultante, que es igual al número de dígitos.

Nota: la expresión no valida que lo ingresado sea sólo dígitos.

Ahora, si lo quieres convertido en función:

```
def contar(numero):
    return len(numero.strip())
```

**Versión con validación**

Ahora, si queremos una función que cuente correctamente los dígitos en cadenas como "+123.00", podemos recurrir a expresiones regulares:

```
import re

patron = re.compile("\d")

def contar(numero):
    return len(re.findall(patron, numero))

numero = "+123.00"

print(contar(numero))
```

produce:

```
5
```

**Explicación**

El patrón `\d` reconoce exactamente un dígito dentro de una cadena.

La función `findall` busca un patrón dentro de una cadena y retorna una lista conteniendo todas las instancias encontradas. Así,

```
re.findall(patron, "+123.00")
```

retorna

```
['1', '2', '3', '0', '0']
```

De ahí, lo único que queda es contar los elementos en la lista usando `len()`

Answer (score 6):

Se puede hacer desde las matemáticas.

`10^1 = 10` (es el primer entero de 2 dígitos)... `10^2 = 100` (es es el primer entero de 3 dígitos)... y así sucesivamente. El logaritmo de base 10 `log10()` es justo la inversa: a qué número hay que elevar a 10 para igualar *x*.

```
import math
    
numero = 12345654321
largo = int( math.log10(numero) ) + 1     # -> 11
```

Funciona para enteros positivos que no sean extremadamente grandes. Para cero se agrega un `if`, para negativos se toma `-numero` (y ahí depende si se quiere contar el signo o no).